# Unable to Use GPU in Drone Pipeline with Docker

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, nvidia, drone.io

I am currently working on a pipeline using Drone and Docker to perform GPU-related tasks, but I'm facing an issue where the GPU doesn't seem to be accessible within the pipeline.

It's worth mentioning that when I separately run the PyTorch image on my host machine, torch.cuda.is_available() returns True, indicating that the GPU is accessible.

Here are the details of my testing environment:

1. Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
2. GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090
3. Drone version: v2.18.0

I have a simple pipeline defined in my .drone.yml file as follows:

```
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: default

steps:
- name: gpu-test
  image: 192.168.52.47:5000/test:1.0
  commands:
  - echo world
  - python -c 'import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())'
  environment:
    NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: all
```

this pipeline would return **false** with torch